# I'm sending text/html only emails with zend framework how can I send multipart to include a text only version?

Tags: zend-framework, email

I'm using the code below which sends an html email using a template as the body. How can I include a text only version along with the html version? I'd like to use another template which would be all text to include.

Thanks

```
$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.domain.com', $config);
$HTMLText = $html->render('forgot-password.phtml');
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setHeaderEncoding(Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64);
$mail->setBodyHtml($HTMLText);
$mail->setFrom('name@domain.com', 'Name');
$mail->addTo($userDataPost['user_email']);
$mail->setSubject('Your new password');
$mail->send($transport);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setBodyText(string) function?

Comment: Does this simply add the text version into the body of the email without needing to do any other code changes?